# Expanding the argument to \begin

Tags: environments, expansion

I have some environments `foo` and `bar` that I would like to replace with the environments `newfoo` and `newbar` with the words "This is a modified foo/bar environment:" added before the environment. I am trying to do it in a loop, like so:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\let\bar\relax

\newtheorem{foo}{Foo}
\newtheorem{bar}{Bar}
\newtheorem{newfoo}{New Foo}
\newtheorem{newbar}{New Bar}

\makeatletter
\@for\@env:=foo,bar\do{%
  \renewenvironment{\@env}{%
    This is a modified \@env environment: 
    \begin{new\@env}
  }{%
    \end{new\@env}
  }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{foo}
I want this to be New Foo.
\end{foo}

\begin{bar}
I want this to be New Bar.
\end{bar}
\end{document}
```

However, this does not work because `\begin` does not want to expand the command `\@env`. I have unsuccessfully tried to add `\expandafter`s there, but I did not manage to make it work. I have also attempted to circumvent it by using

```
\renewenvironment{\@env}{%
        This is a modified \@env environment: 
        \csname new\@env\endcsname
 }{%
        \csname endnew\@env\endcsname
 }%
```

but apparently this does not work either (I'm not actually sure why).

Can someone suggest a working solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the expansion of `\@env`, not `\@env`. It's easier with `expl3`. In the second argument of `\xfor`, `#1` denotes the current item in the list being processed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\let\bar\relax

\newtheorem{foo}{Foo}
\newtheorem{bar}{Bar}
\newtheorem{newfoo}{New Foo}
\newtheorem{newbar}{New Bar}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xfor}{mm}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\xfor{foo,bar}{%
  \renewenvironment{#1}{%
    This is a modified #1 environment: 
    \begin{new#1}
  }{%
    \end{new#1}
  }%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{foo}
I want this to be New Foo.
\end{foo}

\begin{bar}
I want this to be New Bar.
\end{bar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Without the use of `expl3` you might use:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\let\bar\relax

% not necessary because we don't use \renewenvironment but define the macros used for the environment later
%\newtheorem{foo}{Foo}
%\newtheorem{bar}{Bar}

\newtheorem{newfoo}{New Foo}
\newtheorem{newbar}{New Bar}

\makeatletter
\@for\@env:=foo,bar\do{%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname\@env\endcsname{%
        This is a modified \@env\ environment:
        \noexpand\begin{new\@env}}
    \expandafter\xdef\csname end\@env\endcsname{\noexpand\end{new\@env}}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{foo}
I want this to be New Foo.
\end{foo}

\begin{bar}
I want this to be New Bar.
\end{bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This might be very dangerous if the `This is a modified...` part contains commands.

Comment: @egreg yes, in this case one would have to insert some `\noexpand`s. I just wanted to show a way without `expl3` for academic purposes.

Comment: @egreg I'm curious, in what way is it dangerous?

Comment: @Mereenie imagine you want to use a command inside of the definition which must not be expanded there (for any reason, e.g. being defined later). You'd have to mark it with `\noexpand` every time you use such a macro (because of `\xdef` expanding every expandable macro during the definition). That's what makes it not that user friendly and prone to errors.